# bash command substitution remove quotation

Tags: bash

I did a little experiment with the bash and even after reading the relevant parts of the advanced bash scripting guide I can't explain what I'm observing.

Test situation: A directory named "test" with a subdirectory "target" and two files: "a b" and "c d" (the names contain blanks). I want to move the files into the target directory and I'm making it way more complicated then necessary:

```
cp $(echo "'a b' 'c d'") target
```

This gives me the following result:

```
cp: Aufruf von stat für „'a“ nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cp: Aufruf von stat für „b'“ nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cp: Aufruf von stat für „'c“ nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cp: Aufruf von stat für „d'“ nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

It is as if something is removing the single quotation marks from the output of the inner echo command. But if I do a:

```
echo $(echo "'a b' 'c d'")
```

the result is:

```
'a b' 'c d'
```

Can some bash guru point me to the documentation that makes me understand that? This would make my friday complete!

Edit: I realized too late, that the 's are not removed but ignored. This is even more confusing to me and needs to be explained as well.

Comment: Word splitting fun...although what's wrong with `cp 'a b' 'c d' target`? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Interestingly, if you do `echo $(echo $(echo "'a b' 'c d'"))`, you'll still get `'a b' 'c d'`.

Comment: I belive @TomFenech pointed you in the right direction with word splitting, see here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html .

Comment: @Tom: It's just educational!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your approach isn't working:

```
cp $(echo "'a b' 'c d'") target
```

The command substitution (the bit between `$(` and `)`) is subject to **word splitting**. Your use of double quotes mean that `echo` sees only one argument. However, the parent shell splits the output of `echo` on white space into `'a b'`, `'c` and `d'`, i.e. four separate words.

As always, using `set -x` helps to visualise these things:

```
$ cp $(echo "'a b' 'c d'") target
++ echo ''\''a b'\'' '\''c d'\'''              # the subshell
+ cp ''\''a' 'b'\''' ''\''c' 'd'\''' target    # the parent shell
```

The single quotes show the boundaries of each word (although admittedly in this case, things are a little confused as you have your own single quotes in there too...).

If you were to put double quotes around the command substitution:

```
cp "$(echo "'a b' 'c d'")" target
```

then word splitting would not occur, meaning that the result of the command substitution would be a single word, although this would lead to a new problem:

```
$ cp "$(echo "'a b' 'c d'")" target
++ echo ''\''a b'\'' '\''c d'\'''
+ cp ''\''a b'\'' '\''c d'\''' target
```

Now `cp` is expecting to find a file named `'a b' 'c d'`, which you don't have either.

For the sake of completeness, the best way to copy these files is:

```
cp 'a b' 'c d' target
```

Comment: To summarize: Command substitution is producing the result of the echo command but all " and ' in the result are escaped and therefore have only a literal meaning. Therefore the blanks in the result are not escaped in any way and do seperate the four parts. Bash is a hell of a language to work with!

Comment: Also, see the last part of the `EXPANSION` section of the `bash` man page, "Quote Removal". Quote removal is what removes the double quotes from the argument to `echo` before `echo` is called, but quote removal is not performed on the result of the command substitution, which is why the single quotes are treated literally and as part of the arguments to `cp`.

Comment: I have a quibble with your paragraph about “the output of `echo`”.  I believe that it’s more accurate to say that the output of `echo`, which is passed to the parent shell, is `'a b' 'c d'`, i.e., eleven characters.  The parent shell then splits that string into four separate words.  To see this, start a new shell, type `ls $(echo football game)` (and Enter), `IFS=t` (Enter), and then repeat the first command.  (You can put `"football game"` in quotes; it won’t matter.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `eval cp $(echo "'a b' 'c d'") target` instead of `cp $(echo "'a b' 'c d'") target`

Comment: You are taking the original riddle to a whole new level! I have no clue why this is working... I thougt command substitution is evaluation the expression in a subshell and replacing it in with the $(...) and executing the resulting expression. Why is there a difference between cp $(echo "'a b' 'c d'") target and cp 'a b' 'c d' target?

Comment: Basically, Tom made the right suggestion, why not simply `cp 'a b' 'c d' target` ? If you want to echo the filenames before copying the files, then use `eval` to tell shell to 'run thru that line again' .

Comment: It's just an artificial example to discuss about.

Comment: I thought bash runs through that line after subsitution. Doesn't make any sense to run through that line before substitution since bash doesn't know what to execute.